# Nested loops for specific numbers

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a method that takes in 2 ints `method(int ii, int xx)`.  I want to loop through a range of values but I cant think of a way to do it without hard coding each value.

When ii = 21, i want xx = 19 through 9
when ii = 20, i want xx = 18 through 12

so hard coded it would be:

```
method(21,19)
method(21,18)
...
method(21,10)
method(21,9)
method(20,18)
method(20,17)
...
method(20,13)
method(20,12)
```

this is what i have so far but it doesnt handle spcific cases like i dont want it to do method(4,19)

```
            for(int ii = 9;ii<21;ii++){
                for(int xx = 4;xx<19;xx++){
                    method(ii,xx);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Keep a map of outer loop => inner loop counts, use the map value of the current outer loop iteration count.

Comment: What is the relation between the cases that you don't want?

Comment: I don't understand what the requirements are of your question. Where do the 9 and 12 come from in your example?

Comment: the 9 and 12 are numbers i set

Comment: @Mike, where do the numbers come from?  Yes, you set them but are they algorthmic?  Are the always going to be the same?  Do they need to be configurable outside of your java code?  Are they always ranges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As originally suggested by Edd, you'll want to use a map.  I suggest creating a `Range` class to represent an integer range for the `xx` values, then you can build a map of `Integer` --> `Range` (ii --> xx):

```
static class Range {
    public final int start;
    public final int end;

    public Range(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
}

static final Map<Integer,Range> RANGE_MAP = new HashMap<Integer,Range>();
static {
    RANGE_MAP.put(21, new Range(9,19));
    RANGE_MAP.put(20, new Range(12,18));
    // ...
}

void calling_method() {
    for(Entry<Integer,Range> entry : RANGE_MAP.entrySet()) {
        int ii = entry.getKey();
        Range r = entry.getValue();
        for(int xx = r.start; xx <= r.end; xx++){
            method(ii,xx);
        }
    }
}

void method(int ii, int xx) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard coded but a list in a map could do this for you:

```
private static final Map<Integer,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>(){{
    put(21, new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
        add(19);
        add(18);
        add(17);
        ...
    }});
    put(20, new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
        add(18);
        add(17);
        ...
    }});
}};
```

Holding the map as static and final will mean you're not creating it each time you're using it.

Then you can loop through like so:

```
for(Integer ii : map.keySet()){
    for(Integer xx : map.get(ii)){
        method(ii,xx);
    }
}
```